# Why does my ajax request disappear immediately from firebug console?

Tags: ajax, firebug

Something is going wrong with my jquery ajax-ing.  When in a similar situation before I have been able to open the site in firebug and watch the ajax request in the in the console, seeing exactly what was sent and received.

In my current project for some reason I see the request flash across firebug's console but it disappears almost immediately.  [Here is a video of what's happening](http://screencast.com/t/mryhOpOEEf).

What's going on here?  How do I get that information to remain in the console so that I can explore it?

Answer (score 1):

Wow I'm an idiot.  This is an ASP.NET application and that's an ASP.NET button which triggers a postback!  So of course the console refreshes.  It's a new page.

Duh.  The solution is to make it a normal button.

Still, the symptoms are confusing enough that someone else might run into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it a normal button, you can also use 
[Firebug's Persist button](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Persist)